# Conditional bold font in Quarto doc, using LaTeX and kable

Tags: latex, rstudio, quarto

For one of my tables in a Quarto doc I am trying to write a conditional to bold an entire row of text if one of the values contains a specific character ("-R"). It would be in the column labeled "Interpretation". I have tried a few things and can get this working within the file with the following code but when I render it doesn't result in bold:

```
df.result %>%
  select(Drug, 
         Variant, 
         Interpretation, 
         Drug.Resistance.Prediction) %>%
  mutate(Variant = str_replace_all(Variant, pattern = ",", ",\n")) %>%
  kable(col.names = c("Drug",
                      "Result",
                      "Interpretation",
                      "Drug Resistance Prediction"))%>%
  column_spec(c(2,4), width = "5.5 cm") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")%>%
  row_spec(row = which(grepl("-R", df.result$Interpretation)), 
    extra_css = "font-weight: bold;")
```

Presumably because latex isn't working with the "extra_css" function? I have tried a number of other things and nothing is working.Here is my most recent attempt using mutate and row spec with latex:

```
df.result %>%
  select(Drug, 
         Variant, 
         Interpretation, 
         Drug.Resistance.Prediction) %>%
  mutate(
    Variant = str_replace_all(Variant, pattern = ",", ",\n"),
    bold_row = ifelse(any(str_detect(Interpretation, "-R")), "\\textbf{}", "")
  )%>%
  kable(format = "latex", escape = FALSE,
        col.names = c("Drug",
                      "Result",
                      "Interpretation",
                      "Drug Resistance Prediction"))%>%
  column_spec(c(2,4), width = "5.5 cm") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")%>%
  row_spec(row =which(df.result$bold_row=="\\textbf{}"), # Apply row-wise styling
    extra_css = "font-weight: bold;")
```

Comment: try `cell_spec` in your ifelse

Comment: I would like to bold the entire row if the condition is met, my understanding of cell_spec is that it would apply to the individual cell only? do you mean replace 'bold_row" with cell_spec?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code and data using `dput`?